# Rails, updating records for an invitation system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, invite

I want to allow users to accept invitations, the accept tag is in the invite model itself (so I need to update the table). So far nothing occurs when the user clicks the accept button

View

```
 <% @invites.where(user_id: current_user.id).find_each do |invite| %>
...
 <%= button_to "Accept", accept_invite_invites_path(invite), method: :put %>
 end
```

Routes

```
  resources :invites do
    collection do
      get 'accept_invite'
    end
  end
```

Controller

```
def accept_invite

  @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
  @invite.accept
end

def decline_invite
  @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
  @invite.decline
end

    def set_invites
      @invite = @story.invites.find(params[:id])
    end

 def new
    @invite = @story.invites.new
 end
```

I get "undefined method `invites' for nil:NilClass" if I keep :update as a part of set_invites, removing update allows my code to run, but no changes to the database is made.

Model

```
   def accept
    accept = true
    save

  end

  def decline
    accept = false
    save

  end
```

Console

```
Processing by InvitesController#update as 
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"BDle9fqXHT9ZFctMbO4RvxfPuTQXe2Nq+b6/T29B3xjpYdtMozVUFLiRlaQFtuYzMrBceTQn8OtfGjJTe4wa/Q==", "id"=>"accept_invite"}
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
No template found for InvitesController#update, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 85ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

It's weird because the database is selecting from the user table rather than updating the invites table

So what is the problem? Is the route faulty? My set_invites method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is the problem? Is the route faulty? My set_invites method?

Yes,your ***route is faulty***. As I can see you declared your route on a ***collection***, but you need it on a ***member***. And also you should change it to `put`.

```
resources :invites do
  member do
    put 'accept_invite'
  end
end
```

Comment: Still nothing, no change occurs, Console outputs the same, it selects from the user table rather than updating the invite table

Comment: It does now select from the invites table, but then runs into a "No template found for InvitesController#accept_invite" error

Comment: I solved the template issue, but there is still no update to the table

Comment: Try `update_attribute(accept: true)` in your `accept` method instead of saving.

Comment: update_attribute(:accept, true) worked, thanks! Why did save not work?

Comment: @RailroadTycoon You should use self to save the record. Anyways, please accept my answer.